# Jackson convert List<String> to String

Tags: java, input, jackson

I want to turn the following `List<String> requestBody` into a `String` using `Jackson`

```
[{"userId":"GZiLXipGgoZeZBCy","displayName":"759383","role":"FATHER"}, 
 {"userId":"HKtpZCfBlfMEiYaH","displayName":"291848","role":"SON"}]
```

So I implemented using Jackson and got this:

```
["{\"userId\":\"GZiLXipGgoZeZBCy\",\"displayName\":\"759383\",\"role\":\"FATHER\"}",
 "{\"userId\":\"HKtpZCfBlfMEiYaH\",\"displayName\":\"291848\",\"role\":\"SON\"}"]
```

My code was:

```
    final OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(out, requestBody);

    final String data = out.toString();
```

Can someone please help me fix the `String`?

(My `request` needs to be a `String` not `List<String>`)

Thanks

Comment: you request body looks more like a List of Map

Comment: What do you want the final output to be like? a jsonArray in a string format? Or an invalid json string with a json array inside it?

Comment: I don't understand. If you  want the JSON raw, just read the `requestBody` as a `String`. There's no need for Jackson here at all.